# sIFR 3 works on home page but not others in wordpress

Tags: sifr, sifr3

So it works great on this page: zookacreative.com/blog/

But then it doesn't work on this page: zookacreative.com/blog/funny-stuff/were-stoked-at-zooka

I have no clue. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in sifr-config.js you have a relative path to the swf file containing your font. Change it to an absolute path:

```
var nfslab = { src: 'wp-content/themes/zooka-blog/flash/nfslab.swf' };
```

should be:

```
var nfslab = { src: 'http://www.zookacreative.com/blog/wp-content/themes/zooka-blog/flash/nfslab.swf' };
```

Hope it helps.

/Klaus